# CREATE PROCEDURE gets "Msg 6567, Level 16, State 2" for SQLCLR stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I have an issue getting SQL Server to create the stored procedure for my CLR function.

This is the error I get:

> Msg 6567, Level 16, State 2, Procedure PerfInsert, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   CREATE PROCEDURE failed because a CLR Procedure may only be defined on CLR methods that return either SqlInt32, System.Int32, System.Nullable, void.

What am I doing wrong?

(Updated) C# code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace MiddleMan
{
    public static class MiddleMan
    {
        [SqlProcedure(Name = "PerfInsert")]
        public static SqlInt32 CreateCommand(SqlChars tblString, SqlChars featureName, SqlChars connectionString, SqlChars perfionConnectionString, SqlChars logFile)
        {
            Process compiler = new Process();
            compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\SQL Server C# Functions\\PerfionLoader\\PerfionLoader\\bin\\Release\\PerfionLoader.exe";
            compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = tblString.Value + " " + featureName.Value + " " + connectionString.Value + " " + perfionConnectionString.Value + " " + logFile.Value;
            //compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            compiler.Start();
            return SqlInt32.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

(Updated) SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PerfInsert
    (
        @tblString nvarchar(max)
        , @featureName nvarchar(max)
        , @connectionString nvarchar(max)
        , @perfionConnectionString nvarchar(max)
        , @logFiel nvarchar(max)
    )
    AS EXTERNAL NAME PerfInsert.[MiddleMan.MiddleMan].[CreateCommand]
GO
```

Comment: OK, you can't use `varchar` for parameters, they must be `nvarchar`. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-2014)

Comment: Yeah, changed the variable declarations to nvarchar and still the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should decorate the method with:

```cs
[SqlProcedure()]
public static SqlInt32 ...
{
  ...
}
```

And, SQLCLR doesn't work with `VARCHAR`. You will need to change the T-SQL definition to use `NVARCHAR(4000)`. If 4000 isn't enough then you can use `MAX`, but if input is guaranteed to be no more than 4000 bytes, then 1 - 4000 is more efficient. Might not make a difference here, but good habit to have :-).

Also, is best if you use `Sql*` types for the input parameters. Meaning, use `SqlString` and get the value from `param.Value`.

**Related Posts:**

1. [System.Web in SQL Server CLR Function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252083/30859) (on DBA.StackExchange)
2. [System.Security.SecurityException with CLR Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646726/577765)

#### UPDATE

O.P. confirmed:

> it turns out the issue was I needed to drop the assembly and recreate it. Didn't realize the build version was different.

Meaning, the originally stated error message of "*CREATE PROCEDURE failed because a CLR Procedure may only be defined on CLR methods that return either SqlInt32, System.Int32, System.Nullable, void.*" was likely due to an issue that was already resolved in the code itself by the time the question was posted. That error is not the result of a missing `SqlProcedure` attribute, nor due to specifying `VARCHAR` as a datatype, so it must be due to something that we never saw.

Comment: "How does one decorate the method"? Using the link Dale posted previously? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlprocedureattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Correct. Typing on phone is frustrating. Updated answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I have made the suggested changes and am sill getting the same error. Im wondering how much this is a user error issue :/

Comment: Its worth noting that I have to run to an appointment in 15, so I may not respond again until the morning when I can actively work with this.

Comment: Can look more when I get home, but you need `SqlString`, not `SqlChars`.

Comment: Annnd it turns out the issue was I needed to drop the assembly and recreate it. Didnt realize the build version was different.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* the `SqlProcedureAttribute`.  That's just metadata to tell SSDT to emit the `CREATE PROCEDURE`.  The stored procedure should use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to match `System.String`. EG:

Compile that C# file into a .dll:

```
c:\test> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc /target:library .\proc.cs
```

then:

```
create assembly PerfInsert from 'c:\test\proc.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;  
go
CREATE PROCEDURE PerfInsert
    (@tblString NVARCHAR(max),
     @featureName NVARCHAR(max),
     @connectionString NVARCHAR(max),
     @perfionConnectionString NVARCHAR(max),
     @logFiel NVARCHAR(max)
    )
AS EXTERNAL NAME PerfInsert.[MiddleMan.MiddleMan].[CreateCommand]
GO
```

Comment: Hi David. I finally had time to test all SQLCLR object types and yes, you are correct, the `SqlProcedure()` attribute is not required. In fact, neither is `SqlTrigger()` nor `SqlFunction()` for UDFs. Thanks for pointing that out (+1). In all these years I never once thought to try this ;-). However, I did find that `SqlFunction()` is required if you need to set the `IsDeterministic` and/or `IsPrecise` properties as those are for the Q.O. It's also needed for TVFs to link the `FillRowMethod`. UDAs and UDTs also require their particular attributes. Take care, Solomon...