# System.Security.SecurityException with CLR Function

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

First off, Ill say that this issue is related to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615223/clr-procedure-issue).

However, I'll move everything over here for reference.

The issue I am having is I am still getting the error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PerfInsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 31]
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "PerfInsert": 
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
>   System.Security.SecurityException: 
>      at MiddleMan.MiddleMan.CreateCommand(SqlString tblString, SqlString featureName, SqlString connectionString, SqlString perfionConnectionString, SqlString logFile)
>   .

Even though I believe I have followed all the steps necessary to set this up correctly. I have even gone so far as to verify that SQL Server has permissions to the directory of the files.

Anyone know what else I can check to see what the missing piece is?

Or do I need to make this an "unsafe" assembly?

C# code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace MiddleMan
{
    public static class MiddleMan
    {
        [SqlProcedure(Name = "PerfInsert")]
        public static SqlInt32 CreateCommand(SqlString tblString, SqlString featureName, SqlString connectionString, SqlString perfionConnectionString, SqlString logFile)
        {
            Process compiler = new Process();
            compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\SQL Server C# Functions\\PerfionLoader\\PerfionLoader\\bin\\Release\\PerfionLoader.exe";
            compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = tblString.Value + " " + featureName.Value + " " + connectionString.Value + " " + perfionConnectionString.Value + " " + logFile.Value;
            //compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            compiler.Start();
            return SqlInt32.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

SQL code(s):

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY PerfInsert
    AUTHORIZATION dbo
    FROM '\\bk-int-1\c$\SQL Server C# Functions\MiddleMan\MiddleMan\bin\Release\MiddleMan.dll'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO


CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [Brock.Retail_Brock.Retail_Brock]
  AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
  FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = '\\bk-int-1\c$\SQL Server C# Functions\MiddleMan\MiddleMan\bin\Release\MiddleMan.dll';

  CREATE LOGIN BrokcRetail
    FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [Brock.Retail_Brock.Retail_Brock]


CREATE PROCEDURE PerfInsert
    (
        @tblString nvarchar(max)
        , @featureName nvarchar(max)
        , @connectionString nvarchar(max)
        , @perfionConnectionString nvarchar(max)
        , @logFiel nvarchar(max)
    )
    AS EXTERNAL NAME PerfInsert.[MiddleMan.MiddleMan].[CreateCommand]
GO
```

Comment: Starting a random external process is *definitely* not SAFE. What's the point of this code anyway? You can execute an external program from a SQL Server Agent job. If you relax security, you can use `xp_cmd` but again, why do that when Agent can do the same *without* relaxing security?

Comment: This looks like a classic case of something better solved with a client application that runs or starts whatever code you need. If you need the ability to trigger it at will from the database end, you can set up a Service Broker queue and wait for requests. Starting an arbitrary process under SQL Server's context is a security nightmare.

Comment: You'd have to use EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE and the code would run under the SQL Server service account. That's *not* a good idea. Whatever you want to do, you *don't* need to use SQLCLR to do it, much less allow unsafe code execution

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fair, but as far as actually trying to learn how to do this, this doesnt help me in my current predicament. What I eventually end up doing may be as you suggest but for my own personal learning I need to figure out how to actually get this working.

Comment: Well, you'll definitely need an `UNSAFE` assembly -- and if you're using SQL Server 2017, you're going to run into [additional difficulties with the new default permissions](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/07/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-1-clr-strict-security) (authored by the same kind soul who answered your other question and who may very well pop up on this one too).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This particular scenario aside, your statement of "_the code would run under the SQL Server service account_" is not necessarily true. It is true by default, but one of the cool things about SQLCLR is that it allows for impersonating the caller's Windows account (if executed by a Windows login; SQL Server logins have no SID to impersonate and so will always be the service account). This is not something one can do with `xp_cmdshell`, or even with the OLE Automation procs (`sp_OA*`).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not blaming or yelling or anything like that. Just clarifying to make sure everyone has accurate info. If you can point me to the doc(s) in question, I will try to fix it.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I wouldn't use SQLCLR for such cases. In fact, at this point I wouldn't use it simply because it doesn't even support .NET Core. Are we going forward with a custom *and* legacy .NET runtime that can't even handle packages, much less work with the *long-term support* runtime versions?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky going back to our old Http, regex and memory usage argument, we now have zero-allocation libraries and classes for HTTP, gRPC - JSON parsing. None of these can be used in SQLCLR though. There's not even .NET Standard support

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I certainly agree that Microsoft has, unfortunately, let SQLCLR support languish, and that it's frustrating and far from ideal. However, I disagree with the notion that "not perfect == not viable". The feature exists and it works in many scenarios, so I don't see an overall problem with using it. Sure, this particular implementation might be ill-advised, and might be better off done via `xp_cmdshell` or SQL Agent job. But, this has nothing to do with SQLCLR in general. It's fine that you don't like or use it, but it's not as bad as you portray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using multi-threading so yes, the Assembly 100% needs to have `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`.

Also, since you already have the Asymmetric Key and associated Login set up (thank you for doing that and *not* using [`TRUSTWORTHY ON`](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/)), you will need to do the following prior to setting the Assembly to `UNSAFE`:

```sql
USE [master];
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [BrokcRetail];
```

and then:

```sql
USE [{db_containing_assembly_hopefully_not_master];
ALTER ASSEMBLY [PerfInsert] WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

or, if you create the Asymmetric Key-based Login and grant it the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission first, then you can simply use `UNSAFE` instead of `SAFE` in the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement.

Starting in SQL Server 2017, you will need to create the Asymmetric Key and associated Login *before* creating the Assembly. The Asymmetric Key and Login go into `[master]` while the Assembly can go into any DB (including `[master]`, but usually best to not put custom code in there).

If you are already using SQL Server 2017 or newer, and if the code shown in the question is in the actual order in which you are executing it, then I would guess that you have already either set the database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` or disabled "CLR strict security". Otherwise you should not have been able to create the Assembly at all without first having the signature-based login created *and* granted the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission. If I am correct about this, you can re-enable "CLR strict security" and/or turn `TRUSTWORTHY OFF` for that database.

Also, as I noted on your related question (the one linked to in this question), you should be using `SqlString` instead of `SqlChars`. `SqlString.Value` returns a .NET `string` while `SqlChars.Value` returns a `char[]`. Long ago people associated `SqlChars` with `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, and `SqlString` with `NVARCHAR(1-4000)`, but that was only due to Visual Studio / SSDT using those mappings as defaults when generating the DDL to publish the Database Project. But there never was any technical / string mapping between them. You can use either .NET type with either T-SQL datatype.

Also, please exercise caution (and lots of testing) when using multi-threading from within SQLCLR.

Please visit [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/) for more resources related to working with SQLCLR in general.

**Related Posts:**

1. [System.Web in SQL Server CLR Function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252083/30859) (on DBA.StackExchange)
2. [CREATE PROCEDURE gets “Msg 6567, Level 16, State 2” for SQLCLR stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615474/577765)

Comment: Dont you wish you could get a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` instead of a SqlString as input so you can work on it without worrying about temporary strings?

Comment: @SolomonRutsky Thanks again for all your assistance. I got everything working and decided to implement it the way your originally suggested previously. I just wanted to at least get all the moving parts assembled correctly in the event I ever do proceed with this method. Thank again for your assistance!

Comment: @DougCoats You are welcome. Glad I could help. Just to be clear, which way did I originally suggest? Scheduling via SQL Agent, or using a separate Express instance just for this project? Just curious.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252077/system-web-in-sql-server-clr-function  "I really don't see why it can't be a console app that is scheduled in one of those two ways. It looks like you could simply change the project type (to be a console app, compiling to an .EXE file), and be done (outside of scheduling it)."  Basically, I had already acknowledged that this didnt need to be a CLR Function, just another step in a bigger job, however, since I opened the can of worms I felt it was a good exercise to complete anyway, even if I was planning on a different approach..

Comment: @DougCoats Thanks for that update. I added that info to my answer on the original question. And, I _completely_ agree with testing the various options to better understand them so that you can make the best decision, most informed decision. And even if you don't use the new knowledge here, you have that info and experience to take with on other projects that can benefit from this exercise.